# Script shell How to put return line in environment variable

Tags: bash, shell

```
caract="A B"
map="bbb"
for line in $caract
do 
RES_QUERY=$caract" "$map$'\n'$RES_QUERY
done

echo $RES_QUERY
```

I get :

```
A B bbb A B bbb
```

instead of :

```
A B bbb 
A B bbb
```

Comment: `echo` converts newlines to spaces.

Comment: What is your use-case here? for what purpose are you trying to use `RES_QUERY` here. It will be better to use arrays for string interpolation than a plain variable

Comment: BTW, it'd be considerably better form to have your expansions quoted. `RES_QUERY="$caract $map"$'\n'"$RES_QUERY"`. Doesn't make a difference on the right-hand side of an assignment, but avoids serious bugs in numerous other scenarios.

Comment: (and I *do* agree that you should probably be assembling an array, as opposed to a string containing literal newlines).

Comment: ...well, unless you *really* need to export it to the environment, which isn't possible for arrays. Assumption thus far has been that the phrase "environment variable" in the question has just been a misnomer.

Comment: As an aside -- see [Why you shouldn't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), and [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) ("How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field?") for the best-practice alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Please try changing `echo $RES_QUERY` to `echo "$RES_QUERY"` to keep the new lines printed on screen.

Comment: Thank for you answer but i want that the modification included in RES_QUERY=$caract" "$map$'\n'$RES_QUERY automaticaly

Comment: @user6223604, you can't. Changing the assignment lets you arbitrarily change the variable's value, but there's nothing wrong with the value -- the **only** problem is with how you're printing it.